# 'No bean named 'jpaMappingContext' available' on Spring upgrade

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, upgrade

I'm upgrading Spring from 4.3.18 to 4.3.24, Spring Data Commons from 1.7.1 to 1.13.22 and Spring Data JPA from 1.5.1 to 1.11.22. On application start I received error:

```
[RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jpaMappingContext' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634) ~[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145) ~[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511) ~[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481) ~[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
18-Jun-2019 09:28:14.030 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
18-Jun-2019 09:28:14.032 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/rife-devclient-thin-client-portal-rest] startup failed due to previous errors
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756) ~[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687) [?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191-1-redhat]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jpaMappingContext' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:682) ~[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1218) ~[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284) ~[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    ... 62 more
```

Problem is connected with AuditorAware - we are using own implementation (similar to the example from the documentation):

```
public class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Override
    public String getCurrentAuditor() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            return null;
        }
        return authentication.getName();
    }
}
```

When I deactivate auditing by removing

```
  <jpa:auditing auditor-aware-ref="auditorAware" />
  <bean id="auditorAware" class="eu.repository.AuditorAwareImpl"/>
```

from xml, application starts, but auditing doesn't work (which is obvious).

I've found solution to create mappingContext bean:

```
public class MappingContextImpl extends AbstractMappingContext {

    @Override
    protected MutablePersistentEntity createPersistentEntity(TypeInformation typeInformation) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected PersistentProperty createPersistentProperty(Field field, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor,
            MutablePersistentEntity mutablePersistentEntity, SimpleTypeHolder simpleTypeHolder) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It works (application starts and Auditor works), but I'm not convinced to this solution because methods return nulls (I'm not sure what they should return) and for real application never run those methods - I put breakpoints inside and application didn't stop on then on both: app start and create/save audited entity.

Is it correct solution to this error or maybe I'm missing something during Spring version upgrade?